# Hector integration with CQL

Tags: java, cassandra, hector, cql, kundera

Will Hector be integrated with CQL in Cassandra 0.8.1? Is anyone actively developing this or know of it? Also, does anyone know of any other Java clients (like Pelops, Hector, Kundera, etc)  that are being developed to integrate to use the new CQL in the release of Cassandra 0.8.1? Does anyone have any recommendations on which Java client to use while running a Cassandra database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hector does have CQL support now.

You can see a few examples on their GitHub page:

[Hector CQL Github Page](https://github.com/rantav/hector/wiki/Using-CQL)

Also from what I have used only really at beginner level - the Hector library seems to be the most complete and logical to use/understand.

Comment: Do we know if this helped or not?

Answer (score 1):

Kundera does provide support for CQL as nativequery